# Devise - can not get current_user in Application Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise for my application (Ruby 2.0, Rails 4). Everything run well (register, login, etc..). However when i want to get current_user in ApplicationController it always return nil (already logged-in). Here is my code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale

    locale = detect_location
    if current_user && current_user.locale.blank?
      current_user.locale = locale
      current_user.save
    end

    I18n.locale = locale
  end

end
```

Any help?

Thank you,

Comment: Random question: is your browser set to accept cookies to store session cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Are you authenticating on other controllers and not this one?

e.g. using `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the other controllers?

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale =
    unless user_signed_in?
      params[:locale] || 'en'
    else
      current_user[:locale] || 'en'
    end
end
```

I

1. In User Table, there's a field called 'locale'.
2. Noted that user_signed_in? is a helper method from Devise Gem